# I want update entity but dataintegrityviolationexception: could not execute statement SQL [n/a]; constraint SGB.C_PR_PK] occurs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

**Entities**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_CUSTOMER", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"accno", "row"})})
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "sgb.CUSTOMER_SEQ",
        sequenceName = "sgb.CUSTOMER_SEQ",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@FieldNameConstants
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sgb.CUSTOMER_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "NEWLAB_CHRONO", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 0)
    @CobolType(numeric = true,nullable = true)
    private Integer newlabChrono;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ACCNO", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String accno;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ROW", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String row;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SHAKHS", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 1)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String shakhs;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TAR_GAR", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 6)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String tarGar;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ID_ALT1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 12)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String idAlt1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ID_ALT2", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 6)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String idAlt2;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ID_ALT3", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 3)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String idAlt3;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MELLI_ALT", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 12)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String melliAlt;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "BRANCH_ID", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 6)
    @CobolType(numeric = true, nullable = true)
    private String branchId;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "BRANCH", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 6)
    @CobolType(numeric = true, nullable = true)
    private String branch;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "REGION", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 6)
    @CobolType(numeric = true, nullable = true)
    private String region;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SITE", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2)
    @CobolType(numeric = true, nullable = true)
    private String site;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Customer that = (Customer) o;
        return Objects.equals(accno, that.accno) &&
                Objects.equals(row, that.row);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(accno, row);
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_CUSTOMER_PERSON")
@SequenceGenerator(
        name = "CUSTOMER_PERSON_SEQ",
        sequenceName = "CUSTOMER_PERSON_SEQ",
        allocationSize = 1
)
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@FieldNameConstants
public class CustomerPerson {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CUSTOMER_PERSON_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "NEWLAB_CHRONO", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, precision = 0)
    @CobolType(numeric = true, nullable = true)
    private Integer newlabChrono;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ACCNO", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String accno;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ROW", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String row;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SHAKHS", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 1)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String shakhs;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TAR_GAR", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 6)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String tarGar;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "SH_NO", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 12)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String shNo;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "BIRTH_DATE", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 6)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String birthDate;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "MAH_COD", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 3)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String mahCod;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "COD_ME", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 12)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String codMe;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GRP1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 3)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String grp1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "BIL1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 1)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String bil1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "DUP1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 1)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String dup1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "NAME1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 60)
    @CobolType(numeric = false)
    private String name1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FAMILI1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 80)
    @CobolType(numeric = false)
    private String famili1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "PERSON1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 1)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String person1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FATHER", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 60)
    @CobolType(numeric = false)
    private String father;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "HOZE", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String hoze;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CITY1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 40)
    @CobolType(numeric = false)
    private String city1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TEL1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 13)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String tel1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "POST1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 10)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String post1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ADDRS1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 160)
    @CobolType(numeric = false)
    private String addrs1;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "E_MAIL", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 40)
    @CobolType(numeric = false)
    private String eMail;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "FAX1", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 13)
    @CobolType(numeric = true)
    private String fax1;

    //other fields...
    
    @Transient
    private Integer isForeign;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        CustomerPerson that = (CustomerPerson) o;
        return Objects.equals(accno, that.accno) &&
                Objects.equals(row, that.row);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(accno, row);
    }
}
```

**This service has been called in outer service that is @Transactional**

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomerService {

    @Value("${range.trackingCodeThreadLocalKey}")
    private String trackingCodeKey;
    @Value("${customer.sync.isNewRecord}")
    private String isNewRecordKey;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomerService.class);

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final CustomerPersonRepository customerPersonRepository;
    private final CustomerCompanyRepository customerCompanyRepository;
    private final AccountMapRepository accountMapRepository;
    private final AccountTypeMapRepository accountTypeMapRepository;
    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;
    private final CompositeCustomerMapper compositeCustomerMapper;
    private final RangeService rangeService;
    private final ThreadLocalUtil threadLocalUtil;

    public String syncAccount(Long newAccountNumber, CustomerAccountResponseDto galaxyData) {
        Optional<AccountMapEntity> optAccountMapEntity = accountMapRepository.findByNewAccountNo(newAccountNumber);
        CustomerDto customerData = new CustomerDto();
        List<CustomerPerson> customerPersonList = null;
        List<Customer> customers = null;
        CustomerCompany customerCompany = null;
        CustomerDto mappedCompositeCustomerPersons;
        boolean updateRecord = false;

        if (optAccountMapEntity.isPresent()) {
            customerData = getCustomerData(optAccountMapEntity.get());
        }

        String legacyAccountNumber = getLegacyAccountNumber(customerData, galaxyData);
        legacyAccountNumber = StringUtil.addLeftLeadingZero(legacyAccountNumber, Constants.Legacy_ACCOUNTNO_MAX);
        log.info("######legacyAccountNumber. {}", legacyAccountNumber);

        if (CustomerUtil.isCompositePerson(galaxyData)) {
            Customer zeroRowCustomer = null;
            CustomerPerson zeroRowCustomerPerson = null;


            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerList()) &&
                    !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerPersonList()) &&
                    customerData.getCustomerList().stream().findFirst().isPresent() &&
                    customerData.getCustomerPersonList().stream().findFirst().isPresent()) {
                updateRecord = true;
                mappedCompositeCustomerPersons = compositeCustomerMapper.compositeInquiryToCustomerDto(galaxyData, customerData);

                if (mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerList().stream().findFirst().isPresent())
                    zeroRowCustomer = compositeCustomerMapper.toZeroRowCustomer(galaxyData, mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerList().stream().findFirst().get());

                if (mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerPersonList().stream().findFirst().isPresent())
                    zeroRowCustomerPerson = compositeCustomerMapper.toZeroRowCustomerPeson(galaxyData, mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerPersonList().stream().findFirst().get(), mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerPersonList());

                mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerList().set(0, zeroRowCustomer);
                mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerPersonList().set(0, zeroRowCustomerPerson);

            } else {
                zeroRowCustomer = compositeCustomerMapper.toZeroRowCustomer(galaxyData, new Customer());
                mappedCompositeCustomerPersons = compositeCustomerMapper.compositeInquiryToCustomerDto(galaxyData, null);
                zeroRowCustomerPerson = compositeCustomerMapper.toZeroRowCustomerPeson(galaxyData, new CustomerPerson(), mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerPersonList());
                mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerList().add(0, zeroRowCustomer);
                mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerPersonList().add(0, zeroRowCustomerPerson);
            }

            customers = mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerList();
            customerPersonList = mappedCompositeCustomerPersons.getCustomerPersonList();


            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customers)) {
                for (Customer customer : customers) {
                    customer.setAccno(legacyAccountNumber);
                }
            }
            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerPersonList)) {
                for (CustomerPerson customerPerson : customerPersonList) {
                    customerPerson.setAccno(legacyAccountNumber);
                }
            }


        } else if (CustomerUtil.isLegalPerson(galaxyData)) {

            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerList()) &&
                    !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerPersonList()) &&
                    !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerCompany())) {
                updateRecord = true;
                customerPersonList = customerMapper.realPersonToCustomerPersonList(galaxyData, customerData.getCustomerPersonList());
                customerCompany = customerMapper.legalPersonToCustomerCompany(galaxyData, customerData.getCustomerCompany());
                customers = customerMapper.accountToCustomer(galaxyData, customerData.getCustomerList(), customerData.getCustomerPersonList(), customerCompany);

            } else {
                customers = customerMapper.accountToCustomer(galaxyData, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), new CustomerCompany());
                customerPersonList = customerMapper.realPersonToCustomerPersonList(galaxyData, new ArrayList<>());
                customerCompany = customerMapper.legalPersonToCustomerCompany(galaxyData, new CustomerCompany());
            }


            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customers)) {
                for (Customer customer : customers) {
                    customer.setAccno(legacyAccountNumber);
                }
            }
            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerPersonList)) {
                for (CustomerPerson customerPerson : customerPersonList) {
                    customerPerson.setAccno(legacyAccountNumber);
                }
            }
            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerCompany)) {
                customerCompany.setAccno(legacyAccountNumber);
            }


        } else if (CustomerUtil.isRealPerson(galaxyData)) {

            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerList()) &&
                    !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerPersonList())) {
                updateRecord = true;
                customerPersonList = customerMapper.realPersonToCustomerPersonList(galaxyData, customerData.getCustomerPersonList());
                customers = customerMapper.accountToCustomer(galaxyData, customerData.getCustomerList(), customerData.getCustomerPersonList(), null);

            } else {
                customers = customerMapper.accountToCustomer(galaxyData, new ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>(), null);
                customerPersonList = customerMapper.realPersonToCustomerPersonList(galaxyData, new ArrayList<>());
            }

            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customers)) {
                for (Customer customer : customers) {
                    customer.setAccno(legacyAccountNumber);
                }
            }
            if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerPersonList)) {
                for (CustomerPerson customerPerson : customerPersonList) {
                    customerPerson.setAccno(legacyAccountNumber);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(threadLocalUtil.getKey(isNewRecordKey)) && (Boolean) threadLocalUtil.getKey(isNewRecordKey))// todo it seems shoule be !isEmpty
            saveAccountMap(newAccountNumber.toString(), legacyAccountNumber);

        saveCustomers(updateRecord, customers, customerPersonList, customerCompany);
        return legacyAccountNumber;
    }

    public void saveAccountMap(String newAccountNumber, String legacyAccountNumber) {
        AccountMapEntity accountMapEntity = new AccountMapEntity();
        accountMapEntity.setNewAccountNo(Long.valueOf(newAccountNumber));
        accountMapEntity.setLegacyAccountNo(Long.valueOf(legacyAccountNumber));
        boolean ifExist = accountMapRepository.existsByNewAccountNoOrLegacyAccountNo(Long.valueOf(newAccountNumber), Long.valueOf(legacyAccountNumber));
        if (!ifExist) accountMapRepository.saveAndFlush(accountMapEntity);
    }


    //todo check below for save and flush of list
    public void saveCustomers(Boolean updateRecord, List<Customer> customers, List<CustomerPerson> customerPersonList, CustomerCompany customerCompany) {
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(updateRecord) && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customers) && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerPersonList)) {

            if (!updateRecord) {
                customerRepository.saveAll(customers);
                customerRepository.flush();
                customerPersonRepository.saveAll(customerPersonList);
                customerPersonRepository.flush();
            } else {
                for (Customer customer : customers) {
                    Optional<Customer> optCustomerById = customerRepository.findById(customer.getNewlabChrono());
                    if (optCustomerById.isPresent()) {
                        Customer customer1 = optCustomerById.get();
                        BeanUtils.copyProperties(customer, customer1);
                        boolean equals = customer1.equals(customer);
                        System.out.println(equals);
                        String s = customer1.toString();
                        customerRepository.saveAndFlush(customer1);
                        log.info("customer updated");
                    }
                }

                 for (CustomerPerson customerPerson : customerPersonList) {
                    CustomerPerson cpSaved = customerPersonRepository.findCustomerPersonByNewlabChrono(customerPerson.getNewlabChrono());
                    BeanUtils.copyProperties(customerPerson, cpSaved);
                    boolean equals = cpSaved.equals(customerPerson);
                    System.out.println(equals);
// ###################
                    customerPersonRepository.saveAndFlush(cpSaved); //Error occurs here
// ###################
                    log.info("customer person updated");
                } 

            }
            if (customerCompany != null)
                customerCompanyRepository.saveAndFlush(customerCompany);

        }
    }

    public CustomerDto getCustomerData(AccountMapEntity accountMapEntity) {
        List<Customer> customerByAccno = customerRepository.findAllByAccountNumber(String.valueOf(accountMapEntity.getLegacyAccountNo()));
        List<CustomerPerson> customerPersonByAccno = customerPersonRepository.findAllByAccountNumber(String.valueOf(accountMapEntity.getLegacyAccountNo()));
        CustomerCompany customerCompanyByAccno = customerCompanyRepository.findByAccountNumber(String.valueOf(accountMapEntity.getLegacyAccountNo()));

        CustomerDto customerDto = new CustomerDto();
        customerDto.setCustomerList(customerByAccno);
        customerDto.setCustomerPersonList(customerPersonByAccno);
        customerDto.setCustomerCompany(customerCompanyByAccno);
        return customerDto;
    }


    private String getLegacyAccountNumber(CustomerDto customerData, CustomerAccountResponseDto galaxyData) {
        String legacyAccountNumber = null;
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData) && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(customerData.getCustomerList())) {
            Optional<Customer> optCustomer = customerData.getCustomerList().stream().findFirst();
            if (optCustomer.isPresent()) {
                Customer customer = optCustomer.get();
                legacyAccountNumber = customer.getAccno();
            }
        } else {

            Optional<AccountTypeMap> optAccountTypeMap = accountTypeMapRepository.findByAccountTypeCodeAndAccountSubTypeCode(galaxyData.getAccount().getAccountTypeCode(), galaxyData.getAccount().getAccountSubTypeCode());
            if (optAccountTypeMap.isPresent()) {
                AccountTypeMap accountTypeMap = optAccountTypeMap.get();
                String accountGroup = accountTypeMap.getAccountGroup();
                String branchCode = galaxyData.getAccount().getAccountTypeCode();
                String cbiDb = accountTypeMap.getCbiDb();
                String cbiCr = accountTypeMap.getCbiCr();
                String cbkDb = accountTypeMap.getCbkDb();
                String cbkCr = accountTypeMap.getCbkCr();
                GenerateAccountNumberResponse response = rangeService.generateAccountNumber(branchCode, accountGroup, cbiDb, cbiCr, "  25E", "  60A");
                legacyAccountNumber = response.getResponse().getAccountNo().toString();
                threadLocalUtil.addKey(trackingCodeKey, response.getResponse().getTrackingCode());
                threadLocalUtil.addKey(isNewRecordKey, true);
            }

        }
        log.warn("#########  legacyAccountNumber {}", legacyAccountNumber);

        return legacyAccountNumber;
    }
}
```

When I debug OR run the application, `Customer` can update, but when I want to update the `CustomerPerson`, it throws `ConstraintViolationException` on PK for updating entity. Any suggestion? I thought it has something with `equals and hashCodes` but I wrote `equals and hashCodes` the same as the `Customer`.

The outer service is SyncLegacyAccountServiceImpl

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SyncLegacyAccountServiceImpl implements ISyncLegacyAccountService {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GalaxyService.class);

    @Value("${range.trackingCodeThreadLocalKey}")
    private String trackingCodeKey;
    @Value("${customer.sync.isNewRecord}")
    private String isNewRecordKey;

    private final IMQService iMQService;
    private final IAccountRequestService iAccountRequestService;
    private final CustomerService customerService;
    private final GalaxyService galaxyService;
    private final RangeService rangeService;
    private final ThreadLocalUtil threadLocalUtil;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void handleSyncRequest(Event event) {
        try {
            rangeCompensation();
            Long newAccountNumber = Long.valueOf(event.getArgument().get(Constants.KEY_ACCOUNT_NO_MQ).toString());
            CustomerAccountResponseDto galaxyData = galaxyService.getGalaxyData(String.valueOf(newAccountNumber));
            String legacyAccountNumber = customerService.syncAccount(newAccountNumber, galaxyData);
            log.info("legacy no {}",legacyAccountNumber);
            iMQService.send(MQUtil.buildAccountChangeResponse(null, legacyAccountNumber, event.getMessageId()));
            iAccountRequestService.saveSuccessfulAccountRequest(event);
            log.info("saved succed");
            updateRangeToFinal();
            log.info("updateRangeToFinal");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            log.error(exception.toString());
            updateRangeToRevoke();
        }
    }

    private void updateRangeToFinal() {
        Boolean isNewRecord = (Boolean) threadLocalUtil.getKey(isNewRecordKey);
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(isNewRecord)) {
            if (isNewRecord) {
                rangeService.updateToFinal(String.valueOf(threadLocalUtil.getKey(trackingCodeKey)));
                removeFromThreadLocal(trackingCodeKey);
                removeFromThreadLocal(isNewRecordKey);
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateRangeToRevoke() {
        Boolean isNewRecord = (Boolean) threadLocalUtil.getKey(isNewRecordKey);
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(isNewRecord)) {
            if (isNewRecord) {
                rangeService.updateToRevoke(String.valueOf(threadLocalUtil.getKey(trackingCodeKey)));
                removeFromThreadLocal(trackingCodeKey);
                removeFromThreadLocal(isNewRecordKey);
            }
        }
    }

    private void rangeCompensation() {
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(threadLocalUtil.getKey(trackingCodeKey)) && !ObjectUtils.isEmpty(threadLocalUtil.getKey(isNewRecordKey))) {
            updateRangeToRevoke();
        }
    }

    private void removeFromThreadLocal(String key) {
        threadLocalUtil.removeKey(key);
    }
```

**Log**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [SGB.C_PR_PK]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

I know what the ViolationException is in this scenario. But it's very odd, because, in the same manner, the `Customer` entity updates properly. But when it wants to update the CustomerPerson, it throws this exception. And I checked with the  `equals` method to insure the updated object is the same as the Db one (ID-->newlabChrono).

Comment: A) Please specify the line in the code where your error occurs, B) Please paste the complete stacktrace, C) Look into the hibernate logs (Enable debug) if necessary, and paste the SQL Query for this specific request that is causing you problems.

Comment: For A, I wrote the line where error occurs. But here does not support line number :(.
`customerPersonRepository.saveAndFlush(cpSaved)`; //Error occurs here

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Are you creating the tables yourself, or JPA? If yourself, please show the SQL Code, we need to see what determines a PK for your CustomerPerson table, vs Customer.

Comment: It is actually a view and I didn't create it.

Comment: Yes, Alexey Veleshko

Answer (score 0):

`DataIntegrityViolationException` means that your code tries to modify the database in a way that the database scheme forbids. The abbreviation "PK" usually means "Primary Key", therefore your code probably tried to insert a row with a duplicate ID.

Comment: I know what the ViolationException is in this scenario. But it's very odd, because, in the same manner, the `Customer` entity updates properly. But when it wants to update the CustomerPerson, it throws this exception. And I checked with the  `equals` method to insure the updated object is the same as the Db one (ID-->newlabChrono).

Comment: Well, if it's the same, why do you `INSERT` it instead of `UPDATE`ing it.

Comment: when using `repository.save();` or better to say using Spring Data JPA, there is no difference between `save` method for saving or updating.

Comment: Since the error comes from the database I'd look at  the  SQL that the JPA provider generates for your case and identify if it matches your expectations. If it's okay, then I'd try to debug it manually in the database; otherwise I'd try to see why the SQL is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but what could be happening is the following:

```
CustomerPerson cpSaved = customerPersonRepository.findCustomerPersonByNewlabChrono(customerPerson.getNewlabChrono());
```

Retrieves specific CustomPerson with ID=XX

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(customerPerson, cpSaved);
```

cpSaved (ID) is being replaced by this method to maybe ID=YY

`customerPersonRepository.saveAndFlush(cpSaved);` //Error occurs here, (ID) is now YY but that already exists and it is actually trying to create a new OBJECT, rather than updating the entity.

Comment: I also checked with `equals and hashCode` , the ID before and after of `BeanUtils` is the same as before.